# Autocompletion for python script on $PATH

Tags: linux, python, zsh, autocomplete

I have been using zsh with oh-my-zsh.
I have created python script which I would like to call from every catalog in terminal. So I put it on $PATH and it runs from everywhere but my autocompletion do not want to show it when I type the beginning of it and then press [TAB]. I shows me all my aliases, functions, binaries from $PATH but not the script name.

I thought maybe because of *.py in the name of the script so I created a symbolic link to that script with exact name without .py but still no luck. It does not want to autocomplete.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hash -r` (for zsh, in other shells that would be `rehash`), to update the PATH cache.